# Get selected Finder files

Tags: swift, macos

I am starting with Swift and I would like to create an app to load the selected files in the Finder and do something, like in AppleScript.

The bad thing is that I can't find any information about how to do it.

The way to do it in AppleScript is very easy and simple:

```
tell application "Finder" to set theFiles to selection
```

With this code, I can just click the App located on the Finder toolbar and just get the files selected with no effort.

Is there a "Swift" way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can simply execute NSAppleScript

Comment: If you want to do it the swift way you should use NSOpenPanel to select files. For file handling in Mac OS using swift [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/666-filemanager-class-tutorial-for-macos-getting-started-with-the-file-system) is a tutorial that might be helpful

Comment: Thanks. I will try the NSAppleScript option.

Answer (score 3):

With `NSAppleScript` I can get a possible solution....

```swift
func getFromFinder()  -> String{  // Exucute Applescript and Get "Finder selection"

    var scriptToPerform: NSAppleScript?

    let myAppleScript = "tell application \"Finder\" \nactivate \nset theSelection to selection \nset theItems to {} \nrepeat with theItem in items of theSelection \nset theItem to POSIX path of (theItem as string) & \"\n\" \nset theItems to theItems & theItem \nend repeat \nreturn theItems as string \nend tell"

    scriptToPerform = NSAppleScript(source:myAppleScript)

    if let script = scriptToPerform {

        var possibleError: NSDictionary?
        let outputString =    script.executeAndReturnError(&possibleError).stringValue

        if let error = possibleError {
                return "ERROR: \(error)"
        } else {
            if outputString != nil {
                    return outputString!
            }
        }
    }

        return ""
}
```

... But after testing a lot, the `NSAppleScript` option works well by selecting from Finder < 50 files, after that number of files `NSAppleScript` takes too long and I can't capture one by one to populate a progress bar.

The `NSOpenPanel` is surely an option but not to make it like I want.

My thing is to make a "MenuBarApp" or launch the App from Finder-Window-Menu, and capture from Finder Window, the selected files to process. 
Most of the time they are files found after performing a search in Finder, and YES, I know that I can perform the search with the `NSOpenPanel` option, but that's not the thing.

... A couple of hours after, searching and searching I come to this https://github.com/Mortennn/FiScript and looking at the code I came to the following:

**FinderSync (Framework)**
*Enhance the Finder’s user interface by adding badges, shortcut menu items, and toolbar buttons.*
**> FIFinderSyncController**
*The FIFinderSyncController class acts as a bridge between your Finder Sync extension and the Finder itself. Use the Finder Sync controller to configure your extension, to set badges on items in the Finder’s window, and to get a list of selected and targeted items.*
**> > selectedItemURLs()**
*Returns an array of selected items.*

```swift
import FinderSync

let finderController = FIFinderSyncController.default()

guard let selectedItemsURL = finderController.selectedItemURLs() else {
    return
}
```

...But I can't make it work. It always get `nil`.

Some clue please

Comment: Works fine for me. Does you app have access to User Selected Files in the project Capabilities?